# FireFox problem with appendChild image to anchor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, image, anchor

I have very simple code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Add Button" onclick="AddButton();" />
        <br />        
        <div id="divBtnContent">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function AddButton() {
                var divBtnContent = document.getElementById('divBtnContent');
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.href = "http://backticket.com.ua";

                var image = document.createElement('image');
                image.src = "http://backticket.com.ua/Img/addNew.jpg";

                anchor.appendChild(image);
                divBtnContent.appendChild(anchor);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works perfect in all browsers except FF. Why FF doesn't appendChild image to anchor?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect this to be the cause of the problem:

```
            var image = document.createElement('image');
```

There is no *image* element in the HTML and XHTML specifications. You probably meant:

```
            var image = document.createElement('img');
```

After testing in Google Chrome and IE 9 (RC), it appears that they anticipated this kind of developer error and an `<img>` element is created for you instead.

- Original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WUFuu/
- Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WUFuu/1/